# Delete a message from a specific channel if it contains a specific word

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def opt1(msg):
 await msg.channel.purge(limit=100, check= lambda x: ('++' in x.content.strip().lower()) and x.channel.id == 954573387387265024)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if '++' in message.content and message.channel.id == 954573376209420328:
   await opt1(message)
```

What I want to do is if a user types `++` in a channel `954573376209420328` then all the messages that contain `++` in a channel `954573387387265024` will be deleted by a bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def on_message(message):
  purgeChannel = bot.get_channel(954573387387265024)
  if '++' in message.content and message.channel.id == 954573376209420328:
    await purgeChannel.purge(limit=100, check = lambda x: ('++' in x.content.strip().lower() and x.author.id == message.author.id))
```

Okay I figured out it by myself, it was much simpler than I thought

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. You just have to delete `@bot.event` from `opt1` function.

```py
async def opt1(msg):
    await msg.channel.purge(limit=100, check= lambda x: ('++' in x.content.strip().lower()) and x.channel.id == 954573387387265024)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '++' in message.content and message.channel.id == 954573376209420328:
        await opt1(message)
```

Comment: It will delete a message in channel 954573376209420328. What I want is when a user sends ++ in channel 954573376209420328 , every message that contains ++ in a channel 954573387387265024 will be deleted

Comment: My bad. I understood your question wrong. It should work now.